# Lightswitch server with windows authentication and anonymous WCF Services

Tags: c#, iis, wcf-security, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

We have developed a set of applications for our intranet with lightswitch. All of them runs using windows authentication, but now we have to develop some wcf services (hosted in the LS applications) that must allow anonymous connections.

That's the current web.config settings of my exposed services:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows">
      <forms name="Main" />
  </authentication>
  <identity impersonate="true" />
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
   <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataSupport" name="LightSwitchApplication.WCF.HelperService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="LightSwitchApplication.WCF.HelperService.customBinding0" contract="LightSwitchApplication.WCF.HelperService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
   </services>
   <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="LightSwitchApplication.WCF.HelperService.customBinding0">
          <binaryMessageEncoding />
          <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Anonymous" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

After digging here and into msdn I still haven't found if there is a way to reach this behaviour.

Everything works fine when I access to these services with Windows Credentials, i have found no way to use the services with anonymous authentication.
I have tried changing the binding mode, adding this decoration to my services:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[AllowAnonymous]
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Assert)]
[OverrideAuthentication()]
[Authorize(Users="*")]
[OverrideAuthorization()]
public class HelperService
{
  ...
}
```

I have also tried to use the  tag in my web.config, and setting my WCF folder as an application under the main one, but in this case the problems are different, and are related to the compliation path and the dll directory path.
I tried to solve it with:

```
<location path="WCF">
<system.web>
        <authentication mode="None" />
        <compilation>
            <codeSubDirectories>
                <add directoryName="../bin"/>
            </codeSubDirectories>
        </compilation>
</location>
```

But I still receive an error because IIS still doesn´t find my assemblies:
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyApp/WCF/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\WCF\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\WCF\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/MyApp_wcf/88e6cc1b/e1821fec/Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/MyApp_wcf/88e6cc1b/e1821fec/Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server/Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyApp/WCF/bin/Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyApp/WCF/bin/Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server/Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/MyApp_wcf/88e6cc1b/e1821fec/Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/MyApp_wcf/88e6cc1b/e1821fec/Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server/Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyApp/WCF/bin/Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyApp/WCF/bin/Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server/Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server.EXE.
```

Ok, no matter with this... I copy the full bin folder from the parent folder to MyApp/wcf (just for testing, I'll solve it later) and finally the application loads, but... now i get an 401.2 error:

```
Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.
```

I have also created a web.config in the WCF folder, allowing anonymous access in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <add accessType="Allow" users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <identity impersonate="false" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I need help to solve it, because it's driving me crazy. I want to reuse all the business logic defined in our LightSwitch apps, but I still don't know if I'm going to be able for an such 'silly matter'

Can you tell me the right way to get this on, please?

Thanks a lot.